# 'live' updaing of widget's tool tip when the tool tip is shown

Tags: qt

I need a 'live' tool tip for a certain widget. The widget provides a visual interface (basically informing about the progress) to a certain threaded activity. This activity sends out regular messages and I want these messages to be available as widget's tool tips. This is very simple to achieve with `widget->setToolTip(message);` but the problem is that when the tooltip is already shown, the displayed message is not dynamically updated. It is only refreshed when the mouse moves on the widget and tool tip is shown in a different place. I tried to find some solution also with `event()` and `QEvent::ToolTip` but this seems to interfere with tool tips for other normal widgets without 'live' tooltip messsages because `QToolTip::showText()` and `QToolTip::hideText()` has global impact. Any ideas how to hack this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as usual, I find the solution just after I post the question on SO. The method `updateToolTip` checks if a tool tip is shown and only if the mouse cursor is over the widget in question (it is based on the assumption that it does not have child widgets which would need tooltips), the text is updated 'live'.

```
void TaskWidget::updateToolTip(const QString &message)
{
    setToolTip(message);

    if (!QToolTip::isVisible())
        return;

    QPoint p = mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos());
    if (p.x() >= 0 && p.y() >= 0 && p.x() < width() && p.y() < height())
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), message);
}
```